# How does Laravel4 access "statics method" like an instance method?

Tags: php, laravel, inversion-of-control

I am pretty new to Laravel 4. So far I am still trying to understand what facades, dependency injection and IoC really are. (I have been reading a lot about them and I am still at that *"trying to figure it out"* stage).

I believe I will be able to suddenly realize how stupid I have been and understand everything well if someone can explain to me why we can write (something resembles  a ruby class method)

```
$post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
```

like this

```
$post = $this->post->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
```

after we have

```
protected $post;
public function __construct(Post $post)
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->post = $post;
}
```

What makes me confused is that it appears we are accessing a static method here `Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first()`, but after some implementation/magic, we are able to access it like an instance method using `->`.

This is like we just made a class into an object.

But I have a feeling that they are not really statics method to start with (after going through a couple of articles that I not yet fully understand).

Is this facade and/or some IoC tricks at work? What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple: a **Facade is**, actually, **a Service Locator**. It locates an instantiated service (object), inside the IoC Container, and transform a static call made to the Facade in a dynamic call to a object method. So, you are right, they are not really static, those are, in fact, static calls, but then they are forwarded to dynamic ones. Let's take a look at the process:

### Service Instantiation

You this is done by a Service Provider, but that's just a convention, because you can instantiate and stuff objects in the IoC Container whenever you need. This is a basic Service Provider:

```
class MailerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bindShared('mailer-ioc-alias', function($app)
        {
            return new Mailer();
        });
    }

}
```

As you can see, the register method is just binding a closure into the IoC container under the name of `mailer-ioc-alias`. As soon as our application needs to access our mailer, that closure will be ran, instantiating our Mailer and handling it back to the caller. This call is exactly the same as:

```
App::bindShared('mailer-ioc-alias', function($app)
{
   return new Mailer();
});
```

or, since our Mailer has no dependencies and the IoC Container is smart enough to instantiate objects by classes names, even

```
App::bindShared('mailer-ioc-alias', 'Mailer');
```

But, if your class has dependencies, you'll probably forced to go with that closure:

```
App::bindShared('mailer-ioc-alias', function($app)
{
   $mailService = new Mailgun();

   return new Mailer($mailService);
});
```

So, for instance, if you put one of those lines in your routes.php file it would do exactly the same. You wouldn't even need a Service Provider. Bad for design, but maybe good for understanding that what a Service Provider does is very simple. A Service Provider is as complicated as your Service is, if it has lots of dependencies, your Service Provider will probably have lots of methods an instantiation calls.

### Service Location and Dynamic Method Execution via Facade

A Facade, as said, does almost nothing, it basically takes a service alias (mailer-ioc-alias), asks the IoC Container for the instance related to it, and call a dynamic method on the instance it received. This is a full Facade extension:

```
class MailerFacade extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'mailer-ioc-alias';
    }

}
```

As you can see, it has only one method, reponsible for returning the IoC alias of your Service. This class is an extension of `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade`, which has this PHP magic method, responsible for the translation of a static call to a dynamic one:

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
{
    $instance = static::getFacadeRoot();

    switch (count($args))
    {
        case 0:
            return $instance->$method();

        case 1:
            return $instance->$method($args[0]);

        case 2:
            return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1]);

        case 3:
            return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2]);

        case 4:
            return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3]);

        default:
            return call_user_func_array(array($instance, $method), $args);
    }
}
```

It gets the instance of your service, via `getFacadeRoot()`, which will internally call your `getFacadeAccessor()`, and execute the dynamic method on it.

So, this static call:

```
Mailer::send($user, 'myview');
```

Is in fact a dynamic call beautifully disguised as static.

But you can dynamic call your Mailer, anywhere in your system:

```
App::make('mailer-ioc-alias')->send($user, 'myView');
```

Or using the `app()` global function, which returns an instance of your application:

```
app()->make('mailer-ioc-alias')->send($user, 'myView');
```

And inside a Service Provider, and some other Laravel classes, you'll also have access to it via:

```
$this->app->make('mailer-ioc-alias')->send($user, 'myView');
```

All those dynamic calls are exactly what the Facade is doing internally for you.

### The Eloquent Static/Dynamic Conundrum

The 'problem' with Eloquent models is that they don't use a Facades, they are full static classes that don't use the IoC container. When you call:

```
$post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug);
```

It is internally instantiating itself:

```
$instance = new static;
```

Which is the same as doing

```
$instance = new Post;
```

And also returning itself, `to->provide->that->nesting->we->all->love` :

```
return $this;
```

But if you look at the code, you'll see this magic method:

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
{
    $instance = new static;

    return call_user_func_array(array($instance, $method), $parameters);
}
```

This line

```
return call_user_func_array(array($instance, $method), $parameters);
```

Having just one parameter, could be translated to

```
$instance->{$method}($parameters[0]);

return $instance;
```

It does things this way so you further:

```
$post->where('user_id', $user->id);
```

And as it allways return itself, so you can nest calls:

```
$post->where('user_id', $user->id)->where('region', 'US');
```

And it is stateful, so you can keep doing:

```
$post->orderBy('region');
```

Or

```
foreach(Input::all() as $property => $value)
{
    $post->where($property, 'LIKE', "%{$value}%");
}
```

Until you do:

```
$result = $post->get();
```

Or

```
$result = $post->first();
```

When it will build and execute the query, to return a collection or model.

So, the very first call to it is really static, but all the subsequent calls are sent to an instantiated object.